# Installation of nltk and scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have been trying to install and use scikit-learn and nltk. However, I get the following error while importing anything:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/**init**.py", line 57, in 
>       from .base import clone
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in 
>       from .utils.fixes import signature
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/**init**.py", line 10, in 
>       from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
>     File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5029)
>   ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling

I did a `pip uninstall numpy` followed by a `pip install numpy` and also a `pip uninstall scikit-learn` and again reinstalled it. But the error persists.

Comment: try `easy_install --upgrade numpy`. Then you can install scikit-learn by using pip.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem today. Now I have solved it. 
Because I have installed numPy manually, and I use the command "pip" to install the else package.
Solve way:

1. find the old version of numPy.
   You can import numPy and print the path of it.
2. delete the folder.
3. use pip to install again.